# Count Messages with a specific FLAG in INBOX with Curl

Tags: email, curl, imap

I want to query my IMAP server with CURL and count the number of emails in my INBOX. Anybody got an idea how I can do this with Curl? Only the following e-mails should be counted:

- E-Mails in my INBOX
- Unread emails
- The mails have a certain FLAG (e.g. Markus or \Flagged)

To illustrate what I mean by FLAGs:

```
$ curl --url "imaps://mail.example.com/" --user "me@example.com." -X 'SELECT "Inbox"'                      
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft NonJunk martin $label4 $label5 $label3 Junk $Forwarded $label1 ccw $label2 markus $MDNSent 268435456)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft NonJunk martin $label4 $label5 $label3 Junk $Forwarded $label1 ccw $label2 markus $MDNSent 268435456 \*)] Flags permitted.
* 4 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1553791398] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 7246] Predicted next UID
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 27433] Highest
```

Comment: Does curl give access to the SEARCH command?  Number of emails is right there in the EXISTS response.  You can do search for flags (NOT \Seen for unread emails)

Comment: Curl gives access to the IMAP URL, which permits searches. There's an example [starting at the bottom of page 14](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5092#page-14).